Is it possible to reference Xamarin Forms from Win UI 3 project?
The title says it all.
I tried by adding Xamarin forms NuGet reference in the WinUI3 project, but this cased the project to stop compiling and giving the below error. Obviously the above breaks the build.
enter image description here
So, is there a way to reference Xamarin forms and use some of its references like Xamarin essentials in a WinUI 3 project?
I tried by adding Xamarin forms NuGet reference in the WinUI3 project, giving the error.

Why do you want to do this? You're supposed to use MAUI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/) which is an evolution of Xamarin, and WinUI3 will be the target platform for MAUI on Windows.

I'm migrating my UWP project, which currently references Xamarin.Forms, to a WinUI 3 project as the first phase of our migration plan. In the subsequent phase, we intend to migrate from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI. I would like to know if it is possible to include Xamarin.Forms references in a WinUI 3 project. If it is not possible, we may need to handle both migrations (UWP to WinUI 3 and Xamarin.Forms to MAUI) simultaneously.

Yes, that's the idea, migrate UWP to WinUI3 and all Xamarin to MAUI (for which WinUI3 is the target for Windows platform)

I agree with Simon, you should use MAUI. Your existing Xamarin.Forms UWP project can be updated to an SDK-style project for a .NET MAUI WinUI 3 app.
I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Xamarin.Forms UWP project migration
